# javascript : How to write inside popup window

Tags: javascript

I have created one javascript program and I have created movie object and I have created new window called myWin and inside myWin I have created another window called actorWin. Now I want to pass url(myMovie.actor) and description(myMovie.website_actor) inside actorWin when I click on CLICK HERE TO ACCESS TO THE ACTOR WINDOW.  I have tried below method but that is not working. Can anyone suggest me how to write inside actorWin popup window .

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>lab 8</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var myWin = window.open("", "myWin", "height=500, width=500,location,menubar,toolbar,status,resizable");

        function movie(movie_title, website_title, actor, website_actor){
            this.movie_title = movie_title;
            this.website_title = website_title;
            this.actor = actor;
            this.website_actor = website_actor;
        }

        var myMovie = new movie("Before she was Wonder Woman, she was Diana, princess of the Amazons, trained to be an unconquerable warrior. Raised on a sheltered island paradise, Diana meets an American pilot (Chris Pine) who tells her about the massive conflict that's raging in the outside world. Convinced that she can stop the threat, Diana leaves her home for the first time. Fighting alongside men in a war to end all wars, she finally discovers her full powers and true destiny.", 

            "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0451279/",

            "Gal Gadot is an Israeli actress, singer, martial artist, and model. She was born in Rosh Ha'ayin, Israel, to an Ashkenazi Jewish family. Her parents are Irit, a teacher, and Michael, an engineer, who is a sixth-generation Israeli. She served in the IDF for two years, and won the Miss Israel title in 2004.", 

            "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2933757/?ref_=tt_cl_t1");

        myWin.document.write(    
            "<script type='text/javascript'>"  
            +    "function movieWindow() {"

            +   "var movieWin = window.open(\"" + myMovie.website_title + "\" , \"movieWin\", \"height=500, width=500,location,menubar,toolbar,status,resizable\");"

            +   "}"

            + "function closeMovie() {"

            +  "movieWin.close()"

            +   "}"

            + "<\/script>");

        myWin.document.write(
        "<script type='text/javascript'>" 
          + "function actorWindow() {"

          +   "var actorWin = window.open(\"''\" , \"actorWin\", \"height=500, width=500,location,menubar,toolbar,status,resizable\");"

          +   "<p style='color: green; font-size: 150%'>  \""+ myMovie.actor + "\" </p>"
          +   "<a  style='color: pink; font-size: 150%' href= \""+myMovie.website_actor +"\"> Click for more info </a> "

          +   "}"

           +    "<\/script>");



        myWin.document.write(

            +"<script type='text/javascript'>"

            +   "<body style='background-image : url(lab8_images/back.png)'>"
            +   "<h1 style= 'text-align: center; color: white; font-family: monospace; font-size: 200%'> What about this movie? </h1>"
            +    '<br/>' + '<br/>' +'<br/>' 

            + "<p style = 'font-family: monospace; font-size: 150%; color: #ffffff; padding: 0px 15px: 0px 15px; text-decoration: none'> \""+ myMovie.movie_title +"\"  </p>"


            +  "<p style = 'font-family: monospace; font-size: 150%; color: #ffffff; text-align:center; text-decoration: none'> <a style='color:white' href = 'javascript: movieWindow()' > CLICK HERE TO ACCESS TO THE MOVIE WINDOW </a><br></p>"

            +   "<p style = 'font-family: monospace;font-size: 150%; color: #ffffff;  text-align: center; text-decoration: none'> <a style='color:white' href = 'javascript: actorWindow()'> CLICK HERE TO ACCESS TO THE ACTOR WINDOW </a><br></p>"

            +   "<p style = 'font-family: monospace; color: white; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; font-size: 150%'> <a style='color:white' href = 'javascript: closeMovie();'> CLICK HERE TO CLOSE THE MOVIE WINDOW </a><br></p>"

            +   "<p style = 'font-family: monospace; color: white; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; font-size: 150%'><a style='color:white' href='javascript:actorWindow.close();'> CLICK HERE TO CLOSE THE ACTOR WINDOW </a><br></p>"

            +   "<p style = 'font-family: monospace; color: white; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; font-size: 150%'><a style='color:white' href='javascript:window.close();'> CLICK HERE TO CLOSE THIS WINDOW </a><br></p>"
            +"  <\/script>"
            );

        </script>

    </head>
    <body background = lab8_images/back.png>

    </body>
    </html>
```

output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbPIL.jpg

Comment: For cross document comunication,  check out web workers

Comment: I wan to simply write inside actorWin.document.write();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.opener` and `postMessage()` to communicate between browsing contexts

At initial HTML

```
<script>
  let outerWindow = window.open("myWin.html", "_blank");
  window.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
    // pass data to inner window
    e.source.postMessage(JSON.stringify({a:1, b:2}), document.origin); 
  }
<script>
```

at "actorWin" HTML

```
<script>
  window.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data); // message from `window` at initial HTML `document`        
  }
  window.opener.opener.postMessage("inner message", document.origin);
</script>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/99cHuMklH9S9d4Rgf73K?p=info

Comment: I want to open another window from myWin.

Comment: @PoojaPatel That is what occurs at linked plnkr. That is the reason for `.opener.opener` reference, the second previous `.opener` is the `window` we `postMessage()` to

Comment: It opens two window at a time...In my case when I click on different link it should open different window...and in one window I want to write my text

Comment: That is only to demonstrate the procedure. You can adjust code at "outerWindow.html" to open "actorWin" at `click` event. Get the passed text or `JSON` at `message` event and set HTML or text at `document.body`

Comment: I also want to write something inside pop window.

Comment: @PoojaPatel Yes, place code inside of `message` event handler within "actorWin". See updated plnkr. The message from initial `window` is set at a `<pre>` element at "actorWin"